# Как найти элемент который находиться в #document в selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, parse

мне надо найти и кликнуть по элементу который находиться в теге #document, примерно вот структура html кода:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    #document
        <html>
             <head></head>
             <body>
                   <нужный элемент с классом btn_capt>
             </body>
        </html>
    </body>
</html>
```

Я уже пробовал:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn_capt').click()
```

Не получилось пишет что элемент не найден. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изначально найти сам тэг, а потом уже в самом тэге найти нужный элемент.

```
tag = driver.find_element(By.XXX, 'xxx')
element = tag.find_element(By.XXX, 'xxx')
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

В простом варианте в данном случае можно было бы обойтись следующей инструкцией

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#document .btn_capt').click()
```

то есть с помощью [CSS Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) выбрать первый [элемент](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) с классом `btn_capt`, находящийся внутри элемента с идентификатором `document`.

Однако при долгой загрузке страницы или при отсутствии такого элемента произойдет ошибка, поэтому целесообразно ошибки обработать. Ниже приведен рабочий пример:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)  # не закрывать браузер автоматически
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://randstuff.ru/number/')  # в вашем случае ваш URL

selector = '#page .number'  # в вашем случае '#document .btn_capt'

delay = 3  # секунд на ожидание загрузки страницы
content = None
try:
    content = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)))
    print(f"Страница загружена с элементом `{selector}`!")
except TimeoutException:
    print(f"Время на загрузку истекло, элемент `{selector}` на странице отсутствует!")
    driver.quit()
if content is not None:
    content.click()
    print('Все отлично, клик удался!')
```

```
Страница загружена с элементом `#page .number`!
Все отлично, клик удался!
```